Assembled and Linked Win64 Executable showing nothing
I wrote an assembly code
section .data
    text    db "Hello, World!", 10
    length  equ $ - text
 
section .text
    global _start
 
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text
    mov rdx, length
    syscall
 
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

I assembled it using
nasm -f win64 main.asm

and linked it using
link main.obj /subsystem:console /entry:_start /out:main.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO

and I ran the ./main file, but it shows nothing. It was suppose to print hello world.
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Project> ./main
PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Project> nasm -f win64 main.asm; link main.obj /subsystem:console /entry:_start /out:main.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO; ./main
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.41.34120.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\user\Documents\Project>


That is linux code. Either make an ELF file from it and run it using WSL or find a windows example.

But cant it by ran anywhere no matter the operating system regarding 64 bit?

No because it uses linux system calls.

You can assemble and link and run it, but syscall with RAX=1 means something completely different to a Windows kernel than a Linux kernel.  https://github.com/j00ru/windows-syscalls?tab=readme-ov-file has Windows system-call tables reverse-engineered for various Windows kernel versions (because the numbers aren't stable across versions; unlike Linux, it's not a stable API that anyone is supposed to use directly, only the Windows DLLs are intended to use it.)  On some kernel versions, RAX=1 is NtWaitForSingleObject
